# How to debug why a Gradle build failed?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Information:

> Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> C:\Users\davis\AndroidStudioProjects\tester\app\src\main\res\values\dimens.xml
>
> Error:Error: Found item Dimension/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_height
>   more than one time
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   C:\Users\davis\AndroidStudioProjects\tester\app\src\main\res\values\dimens.xml:
>
> Error: Found item Dimension/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_height more
>   than one time
>
> Information:BUILD FAILED
>
> Information:Total time: 6.044 secs Information:2 errors Information:0
>   warnings Information:See complete output in console

Please suggest me any IDE or a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do what the error says.
The item `abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_height` is defined twice in `dimens.xml`. So go to `dimens.xml` and remove one `abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_height`

Comment: Look at this code .............................<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_height">48dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_height">54dp</dimen>
    it's different with dp's but they have same name...that's why gradle showing it as a duplicate .. I'm testing an existing app .. I have to find how the Developer of this app builded the apk.... which IDE may he used??

Comment: There is no official IDE except Android Studio. That xml is ill defined. As for different dimensions you can change the bottom one to "abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_height_1" and search for its uses and change the uses accordingly.